# return 0 in c programing language

Tags: c, function

I don't know the role of the return 0 in the program because whether i add it or omit it there is no deference in exuction of the program.

I try to swap the 0 by 1 the terminal indicate to something wrong.

Comment: "[The return value for `main` indicates how the program exited. Normal exit is represented by a 0 return value from `main`. Abnormal exit is signaled by a non-zero return, but there is no standard for how non-zero codes are interpreted.](/a/204483/15497888)"

Comment: There are some [very loose conventions](https://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/3/sysexits/) that nobody seems to follow.

Comment: I wish the C99 spec hadn't licensed falling off the end of main, it confuses people out of all proportion to the time saved.